# Javascript: obtain visitor's search keyword from document.referrer referred from google search engine

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I open link from Google search result and on opened site in console check referrer

```
> console.log(document.referrer);
https://www.google.ru/
```

Google cut visitor's query keyword from referrer.

Both sites use HTTPS protocol

Any way to get from javascript correct visitor's search query keyword?
(like early in referrer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Google's move to secure search (that is, over HTTPS), the keyword is not passed with the HTTP Referrer data anymore. On Google Analytics you will see this organic traffic under the keyword `(not provided)`